# How can I get a video meta data using Qt phonon?

Tags: qt, video, metadata, phonon

I want to get the bitrate of a video. And I use Qt Phonon to achieve this goal.
Since there is a class called Phonon::MediaObject and provide a method called metaData(),I use that method but the result shows zero. Here is my code, I wonder why and how can I get the metadata such as bitrate in qt with Phonon

```
    QString source="E:\\sh.mp4";
    Phonon::MediaObject media;
    media.setCurrentSource(Phonon::MediaSource(source));
    QMap <QString, QString> metaData = media.metaData();
    int trackBitrate = metaData.value("bitrate").toInt();
    qDebug()<<trackBitrate;
```

The result is 0 all the time

Comment: Did you try dumping all the keys/values from that map to see what it actually contains?

Comment: the size of the map is 0...I don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just figured this out myself.

1. Meta data in video files do not contain bitrate. It only contains extra information about the media that don't have any effect on playback. So even if Phonon::MediaObject::metaData() worked without loading the video, it will not help you.
2. I ended up using libformat, part of ffmpeg library to get the bitrate. Here's the code.

If you copy and paste this, it should work.

Download FFMpeg here: http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/tutorial01.html
This first tutorial will tell you how to link: http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/tutorial01.html

```
#include <QString>
#include <QMultiMap>

#include <stdio.h>

#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libavutil/dict.h>

void processMedia(const char* mediaFile)
{
  AVFormatContext *pFormatCtx = NULL;
  AVDictionaryEntry *tag = NULL;

  // Register all formats and codecs
  av_register_all();

  // Open video file
  if(avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, mediaFile, NULL, NULL)!=0)
    return;

  // Retrieve stream information
  if(av_find_stream_info(pFormatCtx)<0)
    return;

  //Get Bitrate
  float bitRate = pFormatCtx->bit_rate;

  //Get Meta
  QMultiMap<QString, QString> metaData;
  while ((tag = av_dict_get(pFormatCtx->metadata, "", tag,
          AV_DICT_IGNORE_SUFFIX)))
  {
    QString keyString(tag->key);
    QString valueString(tag->value);
    metaData.insert(keyString, valueString);
    printf("%s=%s\n", tag->key, tag->value);
  }

  // Close the video file
  av_close_input_file(pFormatCtx);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you set the data source, the [`MediaObject`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/phonon-mediaobject.html) enters the [`LoadingState`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/phonon.html#State-enum). At that point, metadata might not yet be available.

The object emits a [`metaDataChanged`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/phonon-mediaobject.html#metaDataChanged) signal when the metadata is ready. You should react to that signal and only attempt accessing the metadata once it has been emitted.

Comment: Thank u first, that's the problem I think. If I want to get the meta data without play the video, I mean without let it show on the widget, what  shall I do? Or how can I get the meta data using Qt? Thank u very much.